# passing objects parameter to facebook open graph custom actions in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-opengraph, custom-action

I am posting custom action with facebook open graph api and I am successfully posted that on my timeline with facebook c# sdk.

Here is my action code

```
curl -F 'access_token=AccessToken' \
     -F 'job=http://samples.ogp.me/476622222351784' \
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me/sajidap:apply'
```

Here is my object code

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# sajidap: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/sajidap#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="APPID" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"   content="sajidap:job" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="Put your own URL to the object here" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="Sample Job" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" />
```

I am posting in this way.

```
 var fb = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);
 var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
              { "og:type", "sajidap:job"},
              { "og:url" , "http://www.google.com"},
              { "og:image", "http://www.theappdynamics.com/images/babafooka.jpg" },
              { "og:title" , "Arslan Job"},
              { "job" , "http://samples.ogp.me/476622222351784"}
            };

var Response = fb.post(me/NameSpace:ActionName,Parameters);
```

Its posting an activity on my timeline but its showing Sample activity of an object that is like this url `http://samples.ogp.me/476622222351784`

How I can give my own url, image and title of that object by passing with parameter dynamically from C#. 
Please guide me on this thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its Simple i have done this. You have one page like that which have your Open graphs tags in it like this. Mean It should be some content page on your web.

Let me clear more.. Like I have one resturant and I am selling some chicken burgers and I want to make one action `"Buy"` Mean In facebook it should be like this Arslan buy chicken lawa on link.

1. In This `Arslan` is user who performed the action
2. And Action is `buy`
3. And Object was chicken lawa
4. And URL is my below page who have all open graph tags in it to show in feeds.

Here is ASPX Page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# myapp: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/myapp#"> // Your app name will be replaced with this "myapp"
  <title>Buy Falafeel</title>
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="4735" />  // Your APP ID
  <meta property="og:type"   content="myapp:falafeel" /> // YourAppName:Action Type 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="http://demo.anything.net/buy.aspx" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="Chicken Lawa Falafeel" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="http://www.theappdynamics.com/images/babafooka.jpg" /> 
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     This is Falafeel Page. Demo Demo......
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I am Performing The action on button click from my code behind.

```
void PostAction(string URL, string Token, string Action, string objects)
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient(Token);

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
              { objects ,  URL}
            };

        try
        {
            dynamic result = fb.Post("me/myapp:" + Action, parameters); // again here should be your app name instead of "myapp"
        }
        catch { }
    }

 PostAction("URL", "AccessToken", "Action", "Object"); // Here is The Above Method Call
// Here is URL That URL Who Have Open Graph Tags Like we have created one page with tags named buy.aspx and it should be full link like "http://xyz.com/buy.aspx"
//Access Token Of User On Behalf we are going to create This Action
//Action The One Created On facebook App Setting Of OpenGraph Tag Like "Buy"
//Object That We Also Created On Facebook App Setting For OpenGraph Like "ChickeLawa"
```

Comment: I'm having some difficulty in understanding how do I have a custom title for the actions. For instance in your case you needed 'Arslan' . Say the feed has to be 'Arslan reached level 1' now level 1 can be 2,3,4 and so on. How do I customize the title?

Comment: @FahimAkhter: You need to mention these levels in your pages og Title. Like In My Above Code Falafel Was Level Suppose. When I Need To Go For Jalepeno Chicken I Just Need To Change Type. Thats It

Answer (score 0):

Just publish an action with your object set to the OG URL of your object, as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#create

Anything else (picture, title etc.) will be fetched from the og:tags of the URL.

Comment: you mean that url must have these og tags in it and hold all the information in those tags and facebook will read from that. Right ??